# Is it necessary to encode labels as one-hot in tersorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, prediction, conv-neural-network

I have binary output - '1' or '0'.

I don't encode it as one-hot (since I initially thought that there was no purpose), and when I run my conv net model, I get weird results - all output is '1' and accuracy is ~57%.

I sense something is wrong.

So my question is: **do we always need to encode labels as one-hot**? If so, why **(in the case of binary)**?

My code:

The line `{'class': tf.argmax(prediction, 1)` suggests that there should be multiple output (like a vector) and then we take the one element in a vector with max probability -- **is this interpretation correct?** So it got me thinking that I should probably output 2 labels for a binary output...

Also, I was trying to output the actual probabilities in the line

```
return {'class': prediction, 'prob': prediction}, loss, train_op
```

but it didn't seem to work, and all I am getting eventually was [1 1 1 ...1]

my conv model:

```
def my_conv_model(x, y):

# 1. form a 4d tensor of shape N x 1 x N_FEATURES x 1
x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 1, N_FEATURES, 1])

##########################################################################
##### Conv layer 1 #####
conv1 = tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d(inputs=x,
                                        num_outputs=N_FILTERS,
                                        kernel_size=[1, 7],
                                        stride=[1, 1],
                                        padding='VALID')

# 3. Add a RELU for non linearity.
conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1)

# 4. Max pooling across output of Convolution+Relu.
pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1,
                       ksize=[1, 1, 3, 1],
                       strides=[1, 1, 3, 1],
                       padding='SAME')

##########################################################################
##### Conv layer 2 #####
conv2 = tf.contrib.layers.convolution2d(inputs=pool1,
                                        num_outputs=N_FILTERS,
                                        kernel_size=[1, 7],
                                        padding='VALID')

pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2,
                       ksize=[1, 1, 2, 1],
                       strides=[1, 1, 2, 1],
                       padding='SAME')

last_pool_layer = pool2
last_pool_layer_shape = last_pool_layer.get_shape()
n_cols = (last_pool_layer_shape[2] * last_pool_layer_shape[3]).value
last_pool_layer = tf.reshape(last_pool_layer, [-1, n_cols])
fc_layer = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(inputs=pool2,
                                  num_outputs=10,
                                  activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)

last_layer = fc_layer
    try:
        last_layer_shape = last_layer.get_shape()
        print("last_layer_shape", last_layer_shape)
        last_layer = tf.reshape(last_layer, [-1, (last_layer_shape[2] * last_layer_shape[3]).value])
        print("last_layer_shape", last_layer.get_shape())

        exc_info = sys.exc_info()

        y = tf.expand_dims(y, 1)

        prediction, loss = learn.models.logistic_regression(last_layer, y)
        print("prediction", prediction)
        prediction = tf.Print(prediction, [prediction], message="This is a: ")
        #print(prediction.eval())

        train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
                    loss=loss,
                    global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
                    optimizer='SGD',
                    learning_rate=0.001)

        #return {'class': tf.argmax(prediction, 1), 'prob': prediction}, loss, train_op
        return {'class': prediction, 'prob': prediction}, loss, train_op
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have a bug in that the inputs to your fc are inputs=pool2 and I think they should be last_pool_layer instead.

And to answer your yes tensorflow expects one hot encoding.  You can confirm this for yourself by looking up the implementation of logistic_regression and following that.

If you do you'll end up [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/ops/losses_ops.py#L39) where you'll see it expects labels to be of this form.

```
labels: Tensor, [batch_size, n_classes], labels of the output classes.
```

which means yes to one hot.  also if it isn't one hot it will also mess up the math that you're trying to do by weighting some of the classes more than others.  There might be some function that can convert class label to one-hot implicitly but I don't know about it.